# Aggregating off a join using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have some data which looks like this, lets call it **tb1**:

```
account       date    cost
     A  02-22-2021    1.33
     B  02-22-2021     .35 
     A  02-23-2021     .87
     B  02-23-2021    2.54
     C  02-23-2021    7.42
```

And **tb2** looks like:

```
date     account    grouping
02-22-21       A       alpha
02-22-21       A       beta
02-22-21       A       gamma
02-22-21       B       alpha
02-22-21       B       alpha
02-22-21       B        beta
02-22-21       C        beta
02-22-21       C        beta
02-22-21       C        beta
```

I have two objectives here:

1. I would like to see the ratio of alpha to beta for each group in **tb2**. Date doesnt matter here but basically I would like to see alpha/beta for every account. So something like this:

```
account rate
      A   .5
      B    2
      C    0
```

2. Additionally, I want Cost per alpha for every account. So basically total cost of the account (**tb1**) divided by number of alphas in the account.

```
account  cost
      A   2.2
      B  1.45
      C
```

Thus my final table should look like.

```
account  cost  rate
      A   2.2    .5
      B  1.45     2
      C           0
```

Comment: So what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select
    b.account,
    count(case when grouping = 'alpha' then 1 end) / count(case when grouping = 'beta' then 1 end) rate,
    cost * count(case when grouping = 'alpha' then 1 end) cost
from
    table1 a
    join table2 b on a.account = b.account
    and a.date = b.date
group by
    b.account
```

for daily level you can group by date as well, if your date column is actually datetime , you have to cast it to date first :

```
select
    b.account,
    cast(datecol as date) date,
    count(case when grouping = 'alpha' then 1 end) / count(case when grouping = 'beta' then 1 end) rate,
    cost * count(case when grouping = 'alpha' then 1 end) cost
from
    table1 a
    join table2 b on a.account = b.account
    and a.date = b.date
group by
    b.account
    , cast(datecol as date)
```

Comment: This is good, can i do it also on the daily level?

Comment: sure you can , see second query

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to aggregate each table before joining them together:

```
select account,
       (case when a2.num_alpha > 0 then a.cost end) as cost,
       num_alpha / nullif(num_beta, 0)
from (select account, sum(cost) as cost
      from tb1
      group by account
     ) a left join
     (select account, sum(grouping = 'alpha') as num_alpha, sum(grouping = 'beta') as num_beta
      from tb2
      group by account
     ) a2
     using (account)
```

Comment: this is good, is there a way to do it on the daily leve.

Comment: @JohnThomas . . . This answers the question that you asked, which has no mention of that at all.